# Getting "Error Code: 1191. Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list" when querying multiple columns with FULLTEXT indexes simultaneously

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Using MySQL 8.0, InnoDB Engine. I can query the columns and return results using the fulltext index on individual columns such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (job_summary) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (sub_role) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (region) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (job_title) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (industry) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (industry2) AGAINST ('marketing');

SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (company_industry) AGAINST ('marketing');
```

However, when trying to run something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE MATCH (sub_role, region, job_title, job_summary, 
industry2, industry, company_industry) 
AGAINST ('+marketing' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM all_prod
WHERE location_continent = 'Europe'
  AND mobile IS NOT NULL 
  AND emails IS NOT NULL 
  AND phone_numbers IS NOT NULL
  AND MATCH (job_summary, sub_role, region, job_title, 
   industry, industry2, company_industry) 
   AGAINST ('marketing');
```

I receive the error

> Error Code: 1191. Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to query each column individually and then combine the results afterwards? Eventually this will be part of a search functionality in PHP, I'm just testing the SQL first to make sure it will work as intended..

I have run a TABLE OPTIMIZE statement already, to rebuild the indexes and make sure there wasn't an issue there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `MATCH()` must be the same columns as those in your fulltext index definition, and in the same order.

It sounds like you have created seven individual fulltext indexes, one for each single column.

If you want to run a `MATCH()` against all of the columns at once, you would need to define one index with all seven columns like the following:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX all_prod_ft ON all_prod (
 sub_role, 
 region, 
 job_title, 
 job_summary, 
 industry2, 
 industry, 
 company_industry
);
```

Comment: I've done this, but I think I'm hitting resource limits now as I'm getting the response message: "Error Code: 188. FTS query exceeds result cache limit"

I have 104 GB of RAM, and made sure the 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is set to its max amount... Is this something where it needs the memory just for this query, or to support the fulltext index group in the first place?

Also, now that the columns are all under the same fulltext index, I can't seem to query just a subset of the columns if I want. (I.E. omitting region and job_summary returns the same result as before. Error Code: 1191)

Comment: The arguments to `MATCH()` must be the _same_ columns as those in your fulltext index definition. Not more and not fewer.

Comment: The result cache error might be solved by increasing `innodb_ft_result_cache_limit`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_result_cache_limit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172668/error-188-hy000-fts-query-exceeds-result-cache-limit-mysql